# Image resize before upload on client-side, without flash on IE9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, client-side

I tried several javascript/HTML5 uploader like plupload, but it seems that no one is able to resize image on client side on IE9. I tried to find the current support of HTML5 of IE9 without success.

Is IE9 able to resize image before uploading using HTML5 API ?

Answer (score 2):

The FileReader API is not supported in IE9: http://caniuse.com/filereader

IE10 is supposed to support it though.

Remember that even though you can resize images client side before uploading using a modern browser and the FileReader API, the Canvas resize interpolation is not very good unless you manually program your own interpolation techniques.

Doing so will consume a lot of processing power from the client and the results are not near as good as you get from many server-side image processing frameworks.